# Are PHP sessions stored in /tmp on shared hosting safe?

Tags: php

I have heard that there are security problems that arise because of this. Would it be wise to use purely databases for storing PHP sessions rather than in /tmp?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are unsafe (although the Suhosin extension can encrypt them, providing a little bit of security). You shouldn't need to switch to a database just because of this (although there are other valid reasons to do so). The easiest way is to just set [`session.save_path`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) to a directory only you can access.

Comment: Tell me: Is there a way to restrict access to root ? No. So I think your last sentence is wrong

Comment: If you cannot trust your hoster, you shouldn't even be on shared hosting. Getting the super user involved is kind of trolling, don't you think?

Comment: If you trust hoster, why don't you let session files to be in /tmp ?

Comment: Because on _shared_ hosting, there are other parties involved then the hoster and you, namely the other clients you _share_ the server with. Those are the ones that can either deliberately or by accident cause you harm. And another side issue: if for some reason the server reboots (shouldn't happen, but can), the `/tmp` dir is often emptied, your session dir may not, so if it's a reasonably quick reboot people can get on with their work without having to relogin. Not a security issue, but nice to have nonetheless.

Comment: @genesis φ: Even if you store sessions on the DB you're f---up, if you can't trust SUs, since they can easily read your DB config file or even access the DB directly.

Answer (score 0):

If session data contains sensitive pieces of information, it's unsafe to have it available to anyone you can't trust, of course.

At the same time, database is an external system that reduces overall reliability if your code depends on it, not to mention additional computational overhead as compared to using plain filesystem.

So it's not necessarily a matter of wisdom, but, as always, a matter of using the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

No, they can be readed by your host provider, if you're using shared hosting, if he/she wants
 ...